# How to get Dark Sky API to work using mobile gps

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an app using PhoneGap and although I can get the lat and long from my current position using my mobile phone gps, I can't seem to get weather info out of my dark sky api. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I've tried to use a json script to get the variables lat and long to plug into my api request. There is something I am missing that is needed to bridge the gap.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 

         // device APIs are available
            //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //

            function onSuccess(position) {
                var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
                element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                                    'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                                    'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />';
           var lat = position.coords.latitude;
           var long = position.coords.longitude;
   getWeatherData(lat, long)}        
            }
        function getWeatherData(lat, long){
             var apiKey = "<my API key>";
             var exclude = "?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags";
             var unit = "?units=si";
             var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + apiKey + "/" + lat + "," + long + exclude + unit;

            //get darksky api data
            $.ajax({
              url: url,
              dataType: "jsonp",
              success: function (weatherData) { 
                //weather description
                var description = weatherData.currently.summary;
            $('#weather-description').text(weatherData.currently.summary);
              }
            });
    print(getWeatherData)
      }
    function print(getWeatherData){
     var element = document.getElementById('weather-description');
            element.innerHTML = 'Description '           + weatherData.currently.summary              + '<br />';
    }


    </script>
```

Then in my HTML...

```
  <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>

  <p id="weather-description">Loading Description...</p>
```

Actual results, lat and long and altitude are displayed instead of Finding geolocation, but I expected the weather description to be printed where it says Loading description but it is not.

Comment: Is it printing anything at all in `weather-description`? also have you checked the browser console for errors or tried to `console.log(weatherData.currently.summary)` to ensure you are targeting the correct property.

Comment: No, it's not printing anything but "Loading Description...". The browser console is not returning any errors...

Comment: You never call `getWeatherData()` or at least I can't see where you do.

Comment: Do I do that in the HTML?

Comment: Well you haven't included that part of the `HTML` or explained that you call it within the `HTML`

Comment: I don't think I called it anywhere. I don't know how to do so...

Comment: Try adding `getWeatherData(lat, long)` under/after `var long = position.coords.longitude;` inside of your `onSuccess()` function.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. Then I added a new function:

Comment: function print(getWeatherData){
 var element = document.getElementById('weather-description');
        element.innerHTML = 'Description '           + weatherData.currently.summary              + '<br />';
}

Comment: didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

I worked. Thank you to NewToJS for helping me. The problem was I wasn't calling the function. I've been working on this for 4 days I can't believe it works!